# JQuery Swiper Plugin content disappears when in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using Swiper Jquery plugin with Highcharts chart content.
For some reason i found that when in loop mode, when the slide, with the chart, is reached, after the circle has been completed it does not render/show.

A similar problem was found ( with images - [Image disappears in carousel mode (jQuery Swiper plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355823/image-disappears-in-carousel-mode-jquery-swiper-plugin)) but i think the fix for it does not apply.

I created an example on jsfiddle based on a swiper demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/gondias/gja1j2jh/

When you reach slide 1 from slide 4 does not show anything unless i drag it a little.

```
var appendNumber = 4;
var prependNumber = 1;
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
slidesPerView: 1,
paginationClickable: false,
spaceBetween: 0,
loop: true
});

$(function () {

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Brands",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: "Chrome",
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: "Firefox",
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: "Safari",
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: "Opera",
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]
    });
});
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: As I see the problem is that swiper doens't copy a SVG from highcharts to last slide. In other words, physically it Highcharts are on first slide only, not last.

Comment: Have any idea on how to fix it?